# Build windows phone 8 application with regional language

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, localization, windows-phone

I saw my regional language named  [Malayalam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayalam) in the `Supported Languages list` of my Windows Phone application `WMManifest` file. 
 Is that means that i could display 'Malayalam' language on my WP8 application ? How can i build an application in my Regional language ? 
[image]

I didn't find any sample yet.  Please need support .

> PLEASE NOTE : I copied some words & pasted it as Text property of a
>   Textblock , it displays well in windows phone screen. Are they providing TextBox typing support  in Regional languages?

Comment: it will automatically load in regional format if your device's UI culture is malayalam

Comment: But the keyboard still shows in english language. How can we change it ?

Comment: have you downloaded the Malayalam kb?

Comment: @techloverr oh. bad.! malayalam is not in the kb list .

Answer (score 0):

For that You have to download Regional Keyboard to support that

that can be downloaded from Settings of Windows phone

Comment: oh. bad.! malayalam is not in the kb list .

Comment: @asitis now what can we do?

Comment: don't know what to do with it. Hope they will give Malayalam keyboard support soon.

Comment: But why they put Malayalam under app's supported languages list? The app can display copied Malayalam content even it is not ticked.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 does support the many indic languages, one important thing to know it processes/inputs/displays Malayalam language but doesn't have the Malayalam keyboard. So far it only has support for Hindi in Indic languages.